# GDB failing to record execution in vgdb

Tags: gdb, valgrind

I'm trying to use gdb to record the execution in valgrind's gdbserver like so:

```sh
valgrind --vgdb-error=0 path/to/binary args
```

```
$ gdb path/to/binary
(gdb) target remote | vgdb
0x0000000004001090 in _start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) target record-full
(gdb) c
Continuing.
/build/gdb-GT4MLW/gdb-8.1/gdb/target.c:3132: internal-error: gdbarch* default_thread_architecture(target_ops*, ptid_t): Assertion `inf != NULL' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
Quit this debugging session? (y or n) n

This is a bug, please report it.  For instructions, see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.

/build/gdb-GT4MLW/gdb-8.1/gdb/target.c:3132: internal-error: gdbarch* default_thread_architecture(target_ops*, ptid_t): Assertion `inf != NULL' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
Create a core file of GDB? (y or n) n
Command aborted.
(gdb)
```

I was hoping to use the recorded execution to set a read/write watchpoint and reverse execute to see where it's used. I've been running with valgrind's gdbserver to break on the SIGTRAP emitted when an invalid read/write occurs.

Is this genuinely a bug, or am I doing something wrong/unsupported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valgrind gdbserver does not support record.

See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver-limitations